# Does IMAP maintain "Marked as read" on the server?

Tags: imap

Situation: IMAP mail account A accessed from distinct clients X and Y. X reads a message, is it marked as read for Y? Also, assume message M is marked as read for X and Y, and X marks it "Unread". Is that sync'd to Y?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol#Multiple_clients_simultaneously_connected_to_the_same_mailbox -> http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-5.2 (It's kinda that bad, yeah - it took 5 seconds to google that starting with "IMAP" and reading the wiki, then looking up the cited section in the RFC. Falls under *research effort*)

Comment: Not uninteresting per se, but totally off-topic for this site.

Comment: Ok, I'll fall on my sword - just one more flag needed - tell your friends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, IMAP should do that. It'll sync as long as the clients are accessing the same mailbox.

https://support.google.com/mail/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1668960&page=ts.cs

Comment: Thanks Matthew... I gave you some love on a few other answers of yours